# Mongo Shell query that looks for presence of a count of multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a single, large document that represents applicationState.  I want to build a Mongo Shell query that will tell me if more than one of several conditions is true.

For example, let's say I have three simple, boolean properties...

```
{
  "property1": true,
  "property2": false,
  "property3": true
}
```

and I want to know if more than one of them is true.  If any single one of them is true, I don't want to return a result.  If two or more of any of them are true, I do.

How do I build that query in mongo shell?  Ideally, I'd like a technique that can be used with any conditions and not just boolean checks.

Comment: Programmatically, how are the _"properties"_ selected or assigned? ... from the app/client or some previous aggregation stage?  Might a different data model be useful, e.g., `"properties": [{"name": "power", "value": "on"}, {"name": "temperature", "value": "cool"}, ...]`?

Comment: I can't dictate the storage format. There will be many properties in many different formats.  I need to be able to check for mutually exclusive conditions.  e.g. are any two of (property1 = true), (property2 = 'blue'), or (property3 > 5) at the same time?  If they are, return a result, otherwise don't.  It may be a list of five different conditions and I need to know if any two are present.  I'd love to be able to specify the number (are any 3 or 4 present?), but I'll settle for any 2.

Comment: I'm wondering where the conditions are coming from.  E.g., if the app/client sets the full conditions, then a query could be made to _count_ / _threshold_ the number of true/met conditions.  If the  _"pass"_ / _"fail"_ conditions are determined by some previous aggregation stage(s), the following stages may be more difficult.

Comment: We can assume the conditions will be well defined prior to execution.  We can build the queries manually, we are just wondering what they should look like.  We're very new to MongoDb. All my googling into counting involves counting the number of documents that satisfy a condition.  I have no clue how to count the number of conditions that are true inside a single document.

Comment: Perhaps something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ut8Cqol4uUc)?

Comment: That is the only answer I've seen.  Thank you.